# how to connect to geographically close datacenter

Tags: dns, distributed-system

I am reading a book about distributed systems. One of the options of data replication mentioned is the use of a `multi leader` approach and place each leader in a `different datacenter`. The main point of different datacenters is to be geographically close to the user.

The author then discusses all the write conflicts that emerge by having multiple write leaders, but he doesn't say much on how to direct users to connect to geographically close data center.

For example, user in Austria makes a HTTP request to https://stackoverflow.com. Stackoverflow has datacenters in Germany and North America. DNS record point to the datacenter in US.

Is initial request always going to be pointing to the datacenter in US? I know that once a user is identified, I can instruct all AJAX and img requests to point to Germany (by chaning the html response I sent back), but initial requests, such as page reload will always point to US.

This kinda defeats the purpose of being geographically close to users if they always have to connect to the distant server at first and only after that, the inline resources are fetched from a nearby server.. Am I missing some essential principles here ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible to connect to geographically nearest datacenter. There are lots of companies providing this as a service. eg. Akamai, AWS, Google Cloud, Cloudflare.

This is generally done at DNS level. So when someone makes a request to your domain, the first request goes to the DNS server to resolve the domain-name to IP location. -> This is where the appropriate nearest server location gets resolved.
This is generally used for loadbalancing as well, and called DNS loadbalancing.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I've looked into DNS settings of various hosting providers and I haven't found anything that would signal which IP is appropriate for specific geo location. How does setting geo based DNS look at the practical level?

Answer (score 0):

This is done through Geo DNS, most cloud service providers have this.
[This article](https://constellix.com/dns/geo-dns-services/geo-dns-explained/) has a good explanation on how Geo DNS works.

For example, in AWS one could set up a [Geo Location policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo), this would let you choose the resources that serve your traffic based on the geographic location of your users, meaning the location that DNS queries originate from